# Template does not save to markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, templates, custom-controls

If found a solution to a related question here [Designer problem with CompositeDataBoundControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079563/designer-problem-with-compositedataboundcontrol). But I now have the strange behavior that I can edit the template, after setting the datasourcecontrol correctly, and put in label controls and edit the bindings correctly like I would expect. That is great but when I stop editing the template and look in the source view it is empty?

What do I have to do so that my visual editing of the template is not in vain and that the correct generated markup gets inserted in source view?